# Sudoku generator: Recursion not working

Tags: java, recursion, generator, sudoku

What I'm trying to accomplish:

```
while(there are empty squares)
   get a random number of the remaining numbers
   if(the number hasn't been tried before)
      if(it fits)
        place it and remove from available
        next square
   if(all numbers have been tried)
       forget it
       move back a square and try a different number
```

This loop stops at availableNumbers = 64, and sometimes 37, and sometimes 81 etc. What stops it from going all the way? Why does it sometimes get stuck and sometimes backtrack?

```
while(availableNumbers.size()>0){
            rand = rn.nextInt(availableNumbers.size());
            number = availableNumbers.get(rand);
            if(number != triedNumbers[y][x][number-1]){    // If the number hasn't been tried in this square
                if(!checkConflict(number)){
                    squares[y][x].setText(""+number);
                    availableNumbers.remove(new Integer(number));
                    addedNumbers[y][x] = number;
                    triedNumbers[y][x][number-1] = number;
                    moveAhead();
                }
            }
            if(Arrays.equals(triedNumbers[y][x],refArray)){    // If all numbers have been tried in that square
                emptySquare();    // Forget all numbers tried in current square
                moveBack();
            }
}
```

emptySquare, moveBack, moveAhead and checkConflicts all work like they're supposed to (according to my tests). Here's a gist with them: https://gist.github.com/WQvist/ac4296fb3a86fdc3d713

EDIT: I finally solved it. Thanks for all the help. See my answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but why do you wrap `number` in a new `Integer`?

Comment: Because I want to remove that specific number, not the index. availableNumbers is a list of all numbers that will go onto the board.

Comment: @guy That is incorrect. Since collections work on a 0-based index, the range is actually 0 to `availableNumbers.size()-1`.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but `random.nextInt` is [exclusive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/5168011) the top value, i.e. if `availableNumbers.size()` is 9 `number` will be in range 0 - 8. In `triedNumbers` you use `[number-1]` so you are missing a column.

Comment: @CalvinP. My bad, thanks. I edited the comment.

Comment: @Sinatra From what I can see, the number should be removed properly. However you could try removing the element at index `rand` in `availableNumbers` instead, since that is how you grabbed the number to begin with.

Comment: @guy I think I understand what you mean, but my triedNumbers is a very ugly way of keeping track of which numbers I've tried in that square. if triedNumbers[y][x][0] = 1, it means I've tried putting a 1 there. Therefore, it needs to be number-1, since it starts at 0.

Comment: @CalvinP. That seems a lot more reasonable. Although it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Sinatra I thought as much. Was worth a shot tho. As for keeping track of tried numbers, couldn't you just have an arraylist that is redefined each time you move to a new square? I don't particularly see a need to pass the grid coordinates along with it each time.

Comment: @CalvinP. I tried it along with a simple currentSquare counter, and I think it made it a bit easier. It still doesn't work though. I still get stuck on 60-something and 30-something. I'm starting to think there's something else going on.

Comment: Don't mark your question with `[SOLVED]`: add your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
while(currentSquare<81){
            rand = rn.nextInt(availableNumbers.size());
            number = availableNumbers.get(rand);
            if(square[currentSquare].contains(number)){
                square[currentSquare].remove(new Integer(number));
                if(!checkConflict(number)){
                    squares[y][x].setText(""+number);
                    addedNumbers[y][x] = number;
                    availableNumbers.remove(rand);
                    moveAhead();
                    currentSquare++;
                }
            }
            if(currentSquare < 81){
                while(square[currentSquare].isEmpty()){
                    square[currentSquare].addAll(refList);
                    addedNumbers[y][x] = 0;
                    availableNumbers.addAll(refList);
                    moveBack();
                    if(currentSquare>=1){
                        currentSquare--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your psudeocode is incorrect.  It should be:

```
while(there are empty squares)
   get a random number of the remaining numbers
   if(the number hasn't been tried before)
      if(it fits)
        place it and remove from available
        next square
   while(all numbers have been tried)
       forget it
       move back a square
   try a different number
```

You sometimes have to go back more than one square to get to a square where you haven't tried all the numbers.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I implemented it. Still doesn't work. Thank you.